# Find the remainder from congruence relations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Find the remainder ($x$) $a\equiv x\pmod{73}$ where

$a^{100}\equiv 2\pmod {73}$

$a^{101}\equiv 69\pmod{73}$

$a^{100}\equiv 2\pmod {73}\Rightarrow \phi(73)=72\Rightarrow 100x+72y=(100,72)=4$

This Diophantine equation doesn't have a solution.

Is it necessary to change the base (modulo)?

Comment: $2a\equiv 69\pmod{73}\implies a\equiv-2\pmod{73}$. I don't quite know what you mean by "the remainder of $73\mid a$."

Comment: @Peter Woolfitt, Sorry for the wrong notation. Remainder ($b$): $a=73\cdot t+b$

Comment: ah, well then does my comment answer the question for you?

Comment: I don't understand how did you get $2a\equiv 69\pmod {73}$ from $a^{100}\equiv 2\pmod {73}$ and $a^{101}\equiv 69\pmod {73}$?

Comment: alright, I'll post an answer with more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know 
$$a^{101}\equiv 69\pmod{73},$$
and since $a^{101}\equiv a^{100}a\equiv 2a\pmod{73}$, we have the equation

$$2a\equiv 69\pmod{73}$$

This isn't too hard to just solve, but to make it a little easier, we can note $$69\equiv-4\pmod{73}$$
Hence
$$2a\equiv-4\pmod{73}$$
and so finally
$$a\equiv -2\pmod{73}$$

Since $-2\equiv 71\pmod{73}$, we have $71$ as the solution.